# Asp.Net Validation add custom class

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-core

I am trying to add a class to my div if there is an error in the ModelState. Is there any way to achieve this?

This is how the Html looks like:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label" asp-for="Vorname">Vorname</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Vorname">
     <span class="form-control-feedback" asp-validation-for="Vorname"></span>
</div>
```

Now I would like to add the class `has-danger` to the div arround it if an error occured on the `Vorname` property. Like this:

```
<div class="form-group has-danger">
     <label class="control-label" asp-for="Vorname">Vorname</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Vorname">
     <span class="form-control-feedback" asp-validation-for="Vorname"></span>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

If your form is submitted to the server with no prior on-the-client JavaScript validation (old school! but it works), then you’ve got yourself the easiest of all fixed. You can just add these CSS classes whenever the page loads in the following fashion:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.input-validation-error').parents('.form-group').addClass('has-danger');
});
```

Comment: You can add attributes property like required in your model. check the links -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: you are asking similar question few minutes ago. please delete any one and edit the another. Do not ask similar question twice. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Nope, I asked about something else in the other question, read it again... @Ajay2707